# Jquery facing an strange issue (jsonParse)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, function

i am facing an strange issue in jquery and need your help
i have created the following function in jquery

```
function _renewalMemberShip()
{
var serialNumber = $("#serialNumberUpdate").val();

if(serialNumber != ''){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: path+"query.php?p=viewMembershipRenewal",
    data:{'serialNumber':serialNumber},
    success: function(data)
    {
       var res = $.parseJSON(data);
        $("#memberAddressUpdate").html(res[0]+"\n"+res[1]+"\n"+res[2]+"\n"+res[3]+"\n"+res[4]+"\n"+res[5]);
        $("#lastPaymentModeUpdate").html(data);
        $("#lastPaymentModeUpdate").html(res[0]);
        $("#lastAmountUpdate").html(res[7]);
        $("#lastStartUpdate").html(res[9]);
        $("#lastEndUpdate").html(res[10]);
        $("#Status").html(res[11]+" on "+ res[12]);
        $("#SetStatus").val(res[11]);
        $("#serialNumber").val(res[13]);
    }

});
}
```

the above function is working fine in live site but its not working on localhost.

Comment: ps: Check out `$.getJSON()`

Comment: it shows the null value

Comment: what do you get in res

Comment: with $.getJSON() it shows UNDEFINED

Comment: where is yout path variable

Comment: then `data` is not a json valid string, so the function returns null. Open de result in a texteditor or a validator to check why